# Struggling to get this GUI to work and give me a combobox interface that can select images

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I have written the following code with the intention of creating a tkinter window that has a label as described, a combobox with several selections as described, and a button to display those selected images. This code is nearly there but I am tripping at the final hurdle, please help?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class ConcussionGUI(object):
    """Defines interface"""
    
    def __init__(self, window, graphs):

        """setup the label and button on given window"""
        self.graphs = graphs
        self.ACC_combobox = Combobox(window, values = ["Chronic Cases", "Service Year", "Service Type", "Cause of Injury", "Location", "Age Band", "Ethnicity"])
        self.ACC_combobox.set("Chronic Cases")
        self.ACC_combobox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        self.button = Button(window, text = "Graph", command = self.show_graph)
        self.button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    
        self.label = Label(window, text = "ACC Concussion Data 2010-2019")
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        
    def show_graph(self):

        """Brings in corresponding graph"""
        graph_object = self.ACC_combobox.get()
        select_path = NULL
        if graph_object == "Chronic Cases":
            select_path = chronic_path
        elif graph_object == "Service Year":
            select_path = year_path
        elif graph_object == "Service Type":
            select_path = service_path
        elif graph_object == "Cause of Injury":
            select_path = cause_path
        elif graph_object == "Location":
            select_path = regional_path
        elif graph_object == "Age Band":
            select_path = age_path
        elif graph_object == "Ethnicity":
            select_path = ethnicity_path
        result = NULL
        for path in self.graphs:
            if path == select_path:
                result = path
        load = Image.open(result)
        render = ImageTk.Photoimage(load)
        img = Label(self, image = render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x = 0, y = 0)

    
def main():

    """Set up GUI and run it"""
    template = "/Users/oscarevans/Desktop/{}.csv"
    chronic_path = template.format(chronic_title)
    regional_path = template.format(regional_title)
    ethnicity_path = template.format(ethnicity_title)
    age_path = template.format(age_title)
    service_path = template.format(service_title)
    cause_path = template.format(cause_title)
    year_path = template.format(year_title)
    graph_paths = [chronic_path, regional_path, ethnicity_path, age_path, service_path, cause_path, year_path]
    ACC_gui = ConcussionGUI(window, graph_paths)
    window = Tk()
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: What is the error/issue?

Comment: Shouldnt `ACC_gui` come after declaration of `window`

Comment: There's no way to help you, because this is not a minimal reproducible example. Everyone that runs this code is going to get the same error about `chronic_title` not existing. You didn't post any errors, and your example is not reproducible/executable. How are you supposed to get help? I'll help you with one thing ~ `None` not `NULL`

Comment: correct ACC_gui should, I just switched those two statements around, still issues though. The error statement is:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-13-3a00f30fad1f>", line 23, in show_graph
    select_path = chronic_path
NameError: name 'NULL' is not defined

Comment: Right, `NULL` is not defined because, there is no such thing in python. Use `None`. You have more problems, though. `ImageTk` is not properly imported. There is no such thing as `Photoimage` (it's `PhotoImage`). Your entire `if` chain is a mess, and unnecessary. The way you concoct urls is  also an unnecessary mess. Your `Concussion` class is some kind of weird `"remote" mixin` (just made that up ... so did you). Your namespace was polluted. Your rows and columns were assuming a `1 based` system, but tkinter is `0 based`. My answer fixes all of this and more.

Comment: Your next problems are going to come when you get all of this to "work" and your image pops up over your entire gui with no way to make it go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in the `files` list with all the proper filenames and you're good to go (probably). I refactored/rewrote your entire thing. You had a lot of little mistakes, and a bunch of it was way too verbose.

```
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ConcussionGUI(tk.Frame):
    __graphs = dict()

    def __init__(self, master, graphs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.__graphs = graphs

        tk.Label(self, text = "ACC Concussion Data 2010-2019").grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.ACC_combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=[*graphs])
        self.ACC_combobox.set([*graphs][0])
        self.ACC_combobox.grid(row=1, column=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="Graph", command=self.show_graph).grid(row=2, column=0)


    def show_graph(self):
        choice = self.ACC_combobox.get()
        if choice in self.__graphs:
            graph       = tk.Label(self)
            graph.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.__graphs[choice]))
            graph.configure(image=graph.image)
            graph.place(x=0, y=0)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.configure(**kwargs)

        files   = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
        choices = ["Chronic Cases", "Service Year", "Service Type", "Cause of Injury", "Location", "Age Band", "Ethnicity"]
        furl    = "/Users/oscarevans/Desktop/{}.csv"

        ConcussionGUI(self, {n:furl.format(v) for n, v in zip(choices, files)}).pack(fill='both', expand=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I do however have one more amendment I would like to make if you would still be willing to help. This would be adding a button that returns from the picture file to the starting menu. This would allow me to go back and forth between different combobox options without closing the GUI. Thank you.